# Text wrap around image where image comes last in source. Liquid layout

Tags: css, liquid-layout

I have an image that I want wrap text around it. eg

```
ttttttt|image|    
ttttttt|     |
tttttttttttttt
tttttttttttttt
```

This would be easy if the image was before the text in the source code. However, I need the image to come after the text like this:

text text text text
text text text text
text text text text
text text text text
IMAGE

I don't know the image dimensions or how wide the text will be (as the layout is liquid)

I don't want to use JS

Much appreciated

Comment: can you push your code for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a note for another way to do this...

As long as you are happy for the image to be first in the source (so that it can be floated) you can use display:table-caption to flip the source on small screens where the image isn't floated so

LARGE SCREEN

```
img{
float:left;
}
```

SMALL SCREEN

```
.container{
display:table;
caption-side: bottom;
}

img{
float:none;
display: table-caption;
}
```

Hope that helps someone trying to do something similar. If that's not obvious send me a note and I'll stick some code up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways.

In the image tag:

```
 <img src="http://www.wesleyeterry.com/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" align="left" vspace="4" hspace="4">
```

Or in CSS:

```
<style>
img {
float:left;
margin:2px;
}
```

[http://www.wesleyeterry.com/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png](http://wesleyeterry.com)

Comment: Sorry - my initial question wasn't obvious enough. I needed to do this with the image coming after the text in the source. This works but only if the image comes first.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution to my own question.

This works for me because the reason I want the image to come after the text in the source is that on a small screen I'm not floating it and I want the content to be above the image. If the image was first then it would be too high up a small screen.

My solution isn't very semantic - but apart from that I don't see an issue - possibly another http request so **please** let me know if anyone can see an issue with this.

Here's how I've done it:

Add the image twice. First before the text. Make sure the "alt" is empty.

Then add the image in again after the content. Make sure the alt text is appropriate.

Wrap both images and text in a div and set it to "display:relative"

Set the first image to float right, and its visibility to hidden
Set the 2nd image to position: absolute and position it over the image (easy with the display relative on the container)

The floated image acts as the float for the absolutely positioned one and we don't have to use JS to work out any dimensions so if using a max-width the image will shrink and the text will still act as it should (without any call backs to JS to get the new dimensions)

Then using a media query for the small screen, I've set the first image to "display:none" and haven't applied the absolute position to the 2nd image. So as far as the user is concerned they see content followed by image.

Seems to work well in my initial tests but feels like a hack. Perhaps I could do something with flex-box but I'll leave that for another time. If anyone knows a better solution or can think of a reason why this is really bad then please let me know!

Comment: Thinking about it more. If using JQuery it would be simple to automatically grab the image and duplicate it at the beginning of the container so that there wouldn't be any extra markup. One nice thing I've found is that if I have to adjust something like a margin I can target both images at once.